# What were the results of that question regarding aliens in the Stack Overflow Developer Survey - 2016?

Tags: discussion, survey-2016

As far as I remember, the question went like so:

> Do you believe in aliens?

- So what were the results?
- What was even the purpose of the question?

Comment: I suppose that's confidential? That's why the downvote...? :D

Comment: You'll likely be able to see that when the raw data is released in a few weeks. They probably didn't want to throw it into the result reveal for whatever reason is all.

Comment: Probably aliens are among us.

Comment: You are time-traveling from 2025, what I can figure out from your username.. You might be one of them !

Comment: It was in all likelihood a check question.  If you answer "yes" then your survey answers go on a different pile.  It might be labeled "cookies" but that's just a guess.

Comment: I'd like to see if there is any correlation between ages and Star Trek/Star Wars preference.... *just sayin'*.

Comment: @lad2025 check out the PHP and Android rooms.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just PHP.  The Android room is for 'Do you believe in the supernatural?'.

Comment: Was it not just a way for them to beta test a polling technology?

Comment: Stack Exchange is actually an alien information gathering scheme to learn about us Earthlings. Anyone who answered "yes" is going to be weeded out of the population for knowing too much.

Comment: So, if we are not believing in aliens, then why we have [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) on our network?

Comment: @HansPassant: I agree that it may have been a check question, but I disagree with the labelling. According to me, it should be the other way around. The universe is both *big* and *old*.

Comment: I answered that I do believe there exists an item called "aliens". In fact, I think it's a film.

Comment: But I do also believe in it. It's a great, inspiring film!

Comment: Now that we have had enough of our own opinions, won't somebody provide a serious answer to this question?

Comment: [StackOverflow has several aliens](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=alien), I wonder how much aliens there are in the whole StackExchange network!

Comment: Would Jon Skeet be an alien?