# Can't find answers to "Which books I should read?" in 2016 Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2016

In the 2016 survey, I recall seeing a question **"Which book should everyone read?"** (or maybe it was asking about watching a movie?)

I can't find its answers compiled or mentioned anywhere. Will they be available only within the complete raw answer data?

Comment: You're right, it was the book question.

Comment: Which movie next year then!

Comment: question was closed as off-topic: "...asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource..."

Comment: *votes to re-open*

Comment: It was about books. I submitted Neal Stephenson's *Cryptonomicon* (which, so I read recently, used to be required reading for PayPal employees in their startup period). Love to see others', though. Or are we already in the phase where that question should have a footnote "like a web page printed out"?

Comment: @Rad As I see it, the industry is so driven by fads, that I wrote (totally not seriously), "The Devil Wears Prada." That's why I wasn't sure if the question asked for a book or a movie.

Comment: Yes, presumably you have to wait for the full data dump. Same with [the question about aliens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319311/what-were-the-results-of-that-question-regarding-aliens-in-the-stack-overflow-de).

Comment: FWIW I think I recommended The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.